# Transform tuple type to another tuple type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Suppose I've got a tuple type `std::tuple<x,y,z>`, or maybe `std::tuple<a,b>`. I'd like a general purpose way to transform the types in my tuple, e.g. "functionize" to get

```
std::tuple<std::function<void(x)>,
           std::function<void(y)>,
           std::function<void(z)>>
```

or maybe get storage for shared_pointers like

```
std::tuple<std::shared_pointer<a>,
           std::shared_pointer<b>>
```

How would I achieve this with C++17? C++20 answers interesting but not applicable in my current situation.

**Motivation**:
I've got a class that's going to be parameterized by a list of arbitrary and not necessarily unique types, and would like to have a std::function member for each type in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template specialization is probably the easiest way.

```
template <typename T>
struct functionize;

template <typename... Ts>
struct functionize<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<std::function<void(Ts)>...>;
}

using MyTuple = std::tuple<int, double, char>;
using MyTupleFunctionized = typename functionize<MyTuple>::type;
```

To make it more generic, you can accept a template template parameter to apply to the pack.

```
template <typename Tuple, template <typename> typename Component>
struct transform_tuple;

template <typename... Ts, template <typename> typename Component>
struct transform_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>, Component> {
    using type = std::tuple<Component<Ts>...>;
}

using MyTuple = std::tuple<int, double, char>;
using MyTransformedTuple = typename transform_tuple<MyTuple, std::shared_ptr>::type;
```

The more general solution works best with `c++17` or later. Prior to that it would only match on a template with exactly 1 parameter. After `c++17` it would also be able to match on something like `std::vector` which has 2 template parameters where the second one has a default argument.

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments by @Jarod42 and @Caleth we can improve on this a bit more.

```
template <typename Tuple, template <typename...> typename Component>
struct transform_tuple;
```

A parameter pack for the template template parameter allows us to pass something like a `std::vector` in from `c++11` and forward. That only leaves issues if we want to pass something that mixes type and non-type parameters, like `std::array`.

We can partially solve that issue by using template aliases.

```
template <typename T>
using FixedArray10 = std::array<T, 10>;

using MyTransformedTuple = typename transform_tuple<MyTuple, FixedArray10>::type;
```

Comment: You can do `template <typename Tuple, template <typename...> typename Component> struct transform_tuple;` in C++11

Comment: Prior to c++17, you might still create alias for `Component`: `template <typename T> using Vec = std::vector<T>;` and `transform_tuple<MyTuple, Vec>::type`.(so can handle `std::array<T, 42>`)